# How to Use Notification Delete Intent and Save Notification Details If Notification Not Clicked

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm Using FCM and i Know How to Open Particular Activity When User Clicks it. My Problem is that, i wanna Save the Notification Details If the User Not Opened It. 
I Found Something Like Delete Intent But I Can't Understand it ,Can anyone tell How Can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Delete Intent is a pending intent thats gets called when user clears the notification and you can add a BroadcastReciever to get the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where here you can do something like this.

1. On notification broadcast store first of all store notification data into you db and put this inserted record id in Pending intent Extras.
2. Now while user click on notification at that time you will receive this id in your particular activity from intent extras. get that id from intent extras and delete that recode from your db.
3. In case user in not click in notification at that time your notification is there in your db.

If you want to use **DeleteIntent()** then in that case you need to code like this.

```
notificationBuilder.setDeleteIntent(getDeleteIntent());
```

this line will call getDeleteIntent() while user clear notification.
this getDeleteIntent() method will be like this.

```
protected PendingIntent getDeleteIntent()
 {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("notification_cancelled");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
}
```

This method will send one more broadcast with action name "notification_cancelled". you will receive this broadcast and check the action name will be same at that time you will get that deleted intent data.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("notification_cancelled"))
        {
            // your code
        }
    }
```

Now if you want to store notification data then also pass data to the delete broadcast and receive this data from receiver intent and store in your db.

Comment: Can i Pass the Notification Details In Pending intent??There is any Problem In it???

Comment: you can pass. There is no any problem with that.

Comment: Now I've a Problem If i get Two notification,What I Wanna do?? How Can i Detect Which One Is Clicked and Which One Is Swiped ??

Comment: pass notification data in getDeleteIntent(). While it will call at that time you will receive data of that particular notification which is removed.

Comment: I'm Done But Now Getting "Failed to allocate a 50331612 byte allocation with 3990864 free bytes and 3MB until OOM" ::))

Answer (score 0):

You can use delete intent like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeBroadcast.class);

 NotificationCompat.Builder summaryBuilder = new 
 NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Comment: Thanks For your Answer,Can you Suggest me Any Video tutorial that will be easy to me

Comment: Please Refer this link  : https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: If this answers your question mark this as *answer*